# Rearranging columns of an "almost diagonal" matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, optimization

I have a square matrix that looks like this:
$$
\left(\matrix{
0 & 0 & 17 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 19 \\
14 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 25 & 2 & 0
}\right)
$$

It's obvious that, if I rearranged the columns, the matrix would be "almost-diagonal", in the sense that the sum of off-diagonal elements would be minimized.

Is there a general technique for finding this "most diagonal" column arrangement on matrices bigger than, say, $10\times 10$, but smaller than around $100\times 100$?

A brute-force search over permutations of columns starts to become computationally more intensive around $10\times10$, and really becomes infeasible around $15\times15$, having $k!$ solutions ($k$ being the number of rows/columns).

Comment: One very significant improvement you can make is to compute for each subset of $k$ of the columns the "cheapest way" to put them in the first $k$ slots. This gets your complexity down to $\mathcal O(2^n p(n))$, where $p$ is some manageable polynomial. That's still very expensive for $100 \times 100$, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating your problem into "How do I pick $k$ elements such that I have one element from each row and one element from each column with maximal sum?" (i.e. focus on the diagonal elements, not the off-diagonal elements), we see that this becomes the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

There are algorithms for solving this, for instance the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), which are polynomial time and thus scale a lot better than the brute force algorithm. The Hungarian algorithm specifically, is $O(k^4)$ if implemented naively, but it may be optimised to $O(k^3)$. You can read more about both implementations [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/assignment-problem-and-hungarian-algorithm/).

PS. Note that assignment problems are usually phrased as trying to *minimize*, rather than maximize, the diagonal sum. So you will have to keep that in mind as you implement the algorithms.

Comment: Great observation, I've actually used the Hungarian algorithm before in an unrelated task. I'll mark this as the answer if no others come in soon.